# A high score list: filtering out non-personal bests

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in two columns, sorted by the second column. As follows:

```
A, 1
D, 2
B, 4
A, 6
B, 7
...
```

I need to filter it so that the first column is unique. I.e. the value in the first column only exists once in the result.

```
A, 1
D, 2
B, 4
```

I am keeping track of scores and would like to create a "top 10" list of all of the data. I can sort the data but I have no idea how (if it is possible) to filter out everything but the personal best result from each participant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first column, in column D for example, use the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A5)
```

and the second column, in  column E for example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D:D;A:B;{2}*SIGN(ROW(A:A));0),""))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I understand everything, except why the third parameter to VLOOKUP has to be "{2}*SIGN(ROW(A:A))". Can you explain that?

Comment: It is used to make the `ARRAYFORMULA` work in combination with the `VLOOKUP`. See http://goo.gl/96fdj and http://goo.gl/Fi02r

Comment: @Torben Forgot to hail you !!